# Grant Azure Enterprise App role to B2B external group

Tags: azure, entra-id

In the "External Identities" section of MS Entra, in "Cross-tenant access settings" I've added an Organization and in "Inbound access", "B2B collaboration", I've added the GUID of a group from that organization.

Now, in "Enterprise Application", I want to add that group and assign a role to it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to add a group from an external organization and assign a role to it in "Enterprise Application" of MS Entra. Here are the steps to do so:

1. Sign in to the Microsoft Entra admin center as at least a Security administrator.
2. Browse to **Identity > External Identities > Cross-tenant access settings**, then select **Organizational settings**.
3. Select the link in the **Inbound access** column and the **B2B collaboration** tab.
4. Add the external organization by typing the tenant ID or domain name and selecting **Add**.
5. In the **Enterprise Application** section, select the application you want to add the group to.
6. Select **Users and groups** from the left-hand menu.
7. Select **Add user/group**.
8. In the **Add Assignment** pane, select **Users and groups**.
9. Search for the group you want to add and select it.
10. Select the role you want to assign to the group.
11. Select **Assign**.

For more information on how to manage cross-tenant access settings for B2B collaboration, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/cross-tenant-access-settings-b2b-collaboration.

If you find this response helpful, please consider accepting it.